# Setting the onload property of a child window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a parent opening a new window, and trying to detect when the child window has loaded. In Chrome, I've tried

```
open('http://www.google.com').onload = function() { alert(location.href); };
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Why doesn't the above method work? Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be absolutely certain that a page has loaded, you can use messaging.

If you are able to use HTML5, there is a new feature called [web-messaging](http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/#web-messaging).
This works very well on cross domain sources.

If HTML5 is not an option, use JS instead. I used a simple jQuery plugin called: [windowmsg](http://www.sfpeter.com/2008/03/communication-between-browser-windows-with-jquery-my-new-plugin/). It has worked excellently for me. I'm really not sure about this working on a cross site environment, but I think it should.

Beware of the security issues that these kind of solutions offer.

Answer (score 0):

The method as it is should work(and works for me), but not when opening a window with a document from a different domain.

For security-reasons the new window will not dispatch the load-event to a document from another domain.

Answer (score -1):

Technically speaking the child window and parent window are two different instances of the browser. We call them as child window and parent window. They do not have access to each other.So its not possible to perform any action in one window on the click of HTML elements in second window.

So, I suggest that you should not open a new window if you need access. You can use fancybox or lightbox that is effectively a part of the same window and that, you have control.